# Service working on localhost but not 127.0.0.1?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'm trying to test a webservice, but when I run it in Visual Studio, it's only accessible at (for example) `localhost:9000/api/Maps/1`.  I need it to also be exposed through `127.0.0.1:9000/api/Maps/1` (for testing with an emulator), which currently only gives a 400 error ("Bad request - invalid hostname").

I thought localhost and 127.0.0.1 were meant to act identically.  What's going on here, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about a WCF service. Have you checked the BaseAddress setting in your configuration file?

```
<baseAddresses>
  <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1:9000/service" />
</baseaddresses>
```

Comment: I'm very new to ASP; where in Web.Config (http://pastebin.com/64W80Twm) do I put it?  What does that do?

Comment: Is that the config file for your service? I'm not seeing anything referred to WCF.

Comment: That's the web.config file.  What's the best way to check which type this is?  I'm in a group with three other students, and I don't own this section of the project, so I'm in unfamiliar territory.